# Using a ListBox control in a DataTemplate

Tags: windows-phone-7, datatemplate

I have a simple WP7 Programm where I want to switch between displaying my model objects in a ListBox and a Diagramm.

I want to use Data Templates and a Selector Class which returns the correct template.
The selector takes a boolean property in the view model and returns ListBoxTemplate or DiagrammTemplate

My Page Resources looks like this:

```
      <local:NewTemplateSelector x:Key="NewTemplateSelector">
        <local:NewTemplateSelector.ListBoxTemplate>        
                <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListBox  
                 x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="6,205,35,136"  ItemsSource="{Binding Acts}"                        
                    ItemTemplate="{Binding ElementName=Page, Path=Orientation, 
                    Converter={StaticResource OrientationToListItemTemplate}}" />                                                       
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </local:NewTemplateSelector.ListBoxTemplate>

        <local:NewTemplateSelector.DiagrammTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="Diagramm"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:NewTemplateSelector.DiagrammTemplate>

    </local:NewTemplateSelector>
```

My content Panel has only 1 element:

```
 <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{Binding IsDiagramm, 
    Converter={StaticResource NewTemplateSelector}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
```

I always get a blank screen when I run this.
My Selector class returns the correct template, I can see this in the debugger. 
When I replace the Listbox in the template with a simple textblock, the textblock is displayed, so I suspect a problem with databinding.

But the listbox in the template works fine, when I insert it in my content panel without any data templates.

Any hints for me?

Comment: How and when do you put data in your content control?

Answer (score 1):

You may like to refer to this thread which discusses nested listboxes.

[Listbox Inside listbox Databinding Problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/e23dbe22-2334-4156-b9c6-1ff3c1a8d5af)